# Protect overwriting folder content

Tags: linux, permissions, acl

Is there a way (with acl's) to protect the contents of a folder? Users should create files inside a folder but not overwrite/edit/delete them. Is this possible?

Comment: Also not allowed to edit/delete own files ? I don't think that is possible. The owner of a file could always change its permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One might use `inotifywait` to watch the directory and make changes, such as changing ownership of each new file copied into the directory. In a Debian-based distribution, install the software as follows: `apt-get install inotify-tools`.

Create a script, perhaps `/usr/local/sbin/inbox.sh`, as follows.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
inotifywait -m -e create "/path/to/directory" |
while read path event file; do
    if [ "$event" = "CREATE" ]; then
        chown root:root "$path$file"
    fi
done
```

Give the script permission to execute (`chmod 0700 /usr/local/sbin/inbox.sh`). Then run it at boot time from, say, `/etc/rc.local` or whichever RC file is appropriate: `/usr/local/sbin/inbox.sh &`.

According to the [manual](https://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait), `-m` monitors indefinitely, and `-e` watches for a specific event. Within the `while` loop, it could be possible to receive an event such as `CREATE,ISDIR`, which indicates the creation of a directory, of course. Directories are not the target of the question; thus the `if` statement contains a command to respond only to new files, which are represented with the event, `CREATE`. The `path` variable from `inotifywait` has a trailing slash character, so `$path` and `$file` can be concatenated without specifying a slash between the two.